# Python modules in Sublime textbook not working

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3

I am trying to use Sublime text IDE for my Python projects. But after ensuring the build system, I am not able to run any program there. I am getting `ModuleNotFoundError` as soon as I import modules like `NumPy`, `pandas`.

Here is some useful information:

```
> import sys
> print (sys.executable)

/usr/local/bin/python3
```

The information on pip and Python are following

```
> which pip

/Users/harish/opt/anaconda3/bin/pip
```

```
> which python

/Users/harish/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
```

I have been using pip to install all the python modules.

I have searched extensively internet, I find no solution.
I am using MacBook Pro, macOS Catalonia. (my MPB is an old fart and Apple does not find it worthy to run BigSur)

Comment: are you using the correct virtual environment? if any.

Comment: @oreopot I have no idea what virtual environment is. after installing Sublime text, I installed Python package from command pallet.
I already have Python packages installed and they work fine in Jupyter notebook. but in Sublime text none of them are getting imported.

Comment: This might help you. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VC13MkENVoY

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of the following Python program in sublime: `import sys; print(sys.executable)`. Also, please include the output of the following Terminal commands: `which pip` and `which python`. I'm assuming you installed those modules with `pip`, is that correct? Or did you use `conda`?

Comment: @MattDMo  I have done the requested edits, I have been using pipto install packages. thanks for the help

Comment: @Harish thanks, I'll write up an answer in a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the outputs of `sys.executable` (run within Sublime) and `which python` (run in the shell), you are not using the same Python binary in both places. To set up Sublime to use the correct one where you installed your packages with `pip`, you'll need to create a new [build system](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/build_systems.html).

In Sublime, select **`Tools → Build System → New Build System…`** and change its contents to the following:

```json
{
    "cmd": [
        "/Users/harish/opt/anaconda3/bin/python", "-u", "$file"
    ],
    "working_dir": "$file_path",
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

Hit Save, which will automagically open up your `Packages/User` folder, and save it there as `Python_Anaconda.sublime-build` or something like that. Just don't name it `Python.sublime-build`, as a build system with that name already exists.

Now, select **`Tools → Build System → Python_Anaconda`** (or whatever you named it), and you should be able to run programs with the modules you installed previously.